# Access query to include all values, including Null

Tags: sql, forms, vba, null, ms-access-2010

I have a query that is being generated from a single table. Using the form to set criteria for my query I'm running into issues with null values. I'll simplify my issue below.

**The Table** [Permits]
The table is called Permits.  There is one field that I would like to filter which is called Status.  Within the Status field there are the following entries: null values,"completed" and "Cancelled." Essentially, the null values indicate that a permit status is open.

**In the Form:** [FormQuery]
The form is called FormQuery and has check boxes that will allow a user to select the criteria for their query.  The form has four check boxes with the names: all, completed, open, cancelled.

**In the query:** filtering through [Permits]![Status]
There are a number of fields in the query.  The only field with critera is (Permits.Status).The following criteria is entered:

```
In (IIf([Forms]![FormQuery]![Completed]=True,"COMPLETED",""),
    IIf([Forms]![FormQuery]![Cancelled]=True,"Cancelled",""),
    IIf([Forms]![FormQuery]![All]=True,[Permits]![Status],""))
```

As I understand it `IN(...)` is setting a list of criteria.  The criteria are dependent on the form checks as seen in the `[Forms]![FormQuery]![Completed]=true` section. If the box is checked, a string is passed, otherwise is a "" null value. So when just completed is checked off the list looks like `In (completed)`

The form works.  When I have the "completed" check box selected the query will bring up all completed.  It works similarly with the cancelled and with the all check box.  The one issue is that the code found on the last line, especially the part `[permits]![status]` is only bringing up entries that are populated and null values are being missed.

How would I search for nulls and how would I include nulls in the all query?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the references.  I feel like what I'm doing is essentially taking a parameter query and restricting the input to what is found on the form.  Am I right in thinking that?

Also if I type in the code:

Comment: Also if I try:
IIf([Forms]![FormQuery]![Open]=True,Is Null,"")

I get: This expression is typed incorrectly, or it is too complex to be evaluated.  For example, a numeric expression may contain too many complicated elements. Try simplifying the expression by assigning parts of the expression to variables.

When deleting all criteria and starting fresh I can enter in to the criteria Is Null and get all null values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a wildcard instead:

```
In (IIf([Forms]![FormQuery]![Completed]=True,"COMPLETED",""),
    IIf([Forms]![FormQuery]![Cancelled]=True,"Cancelled",""),
    IIf([Forms]![FormQuery]![All]=True,[Permits]![Status],"*"))
```

You can test this... just put this in your query criteria field:

```
IIf(True,"*","")
```

Run it with False instead of True... experiment.

I recommend you change your method. Use a parameter query but avoid the `IN()` statement. General how-to at http://accessmvp.com/thedbguy/articles/parameterquerybasics.html.

Alternatively, use VBA. General how-to at http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-access/checkbox-filter-form-for-query/ab65c120-6356-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5

Either one is more typical and I believe easier to trouble shoot and maintain.

Comment: Thanks again for sticking with me.  I've experimented with false and true, I've used "*", Like *, Is Null, Null, " " and haven't found success.  I've also just played with a basic IIF code without In, like you suggested, but still cannot get nulls to appear on the condition of a check box returning a true value.

I suppose I could do a parameter query and tell people for open permits to type in "Is Null" it just would look or function as nicely as a form.

Comment: How would a person go about searching out nulls in a parameter query?  If you type Is Null into the dialogue box the query returns no records.  Is the phrase 'Is Null' being turned into a string and not allowed to operate as a command?

Comment: Yes I see.  That is the way of nulls.  So, make a field in the query:  `Status_filter: IIf(IsNull([Status]),"open",[Status])`.  Run your filters on that.

Comment: Thank you very much!!  I didn't realize that you could put functions inside of the field cell.  Your suggestion worked like a charm.